# Any Idea on how I can stop adding multiple entry's of ID's into a database with this code?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to figure a way of allowing users NOT to be able to add the same ID twice as if I wanted to delete one of the users and he shared the ID with another it would delete both.

So far I have found no help doing so does anyone have an idea?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button button;
private EditText IdText;
private EditText NameText;
private EditText AgeText;
private EditText WeightText;
private EditText HeightText;
private EditText ReachText;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IdText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IdText);
    NameText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    HeightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.HeightText);
    AgeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AgeText);
    WeightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.WeightText);
    ReachText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ReachText);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this);
    AddData();


}

public void AddData() {

    button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if ((IdText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        IdText.setError("Please fill out your name");
                        return;

                    } else if ((NameText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        NameText.setError("Please fill out your ID");
                        return;

                    } else if ((AgeText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        AgeText.setError("Please fill out your Age");
                        return;

                    } else if ((HeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        HeightText.setError("Please fill out your Height in centimeters");
                        return;

                    } else if ((WeightText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        WeightText.setError("Please fill out your weight in kilos");
                        return;

                    } else if ((ReachText.getText().toString()).isEmpty()) {
                        ReachText.setError("Please fill out your reach in inches");
                        return;

                    } else {
                        boolean isInserted = dbHandler.insertData(IdText.getText().toString(),

                                NameText.getText().toString(),
                                AgeText.getText().toString(),
                                HeightText.getText().toString(),
                                WeightText.getText().toString(),
                                ReachText.getText().toString());
                        if (isInserted == true)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fighter added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
```

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Fighters.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "Fighter";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID1";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";
public static final String COLUMN_AGE = "Age";
public static final String COLUMN_WEIGHT = "Weight";
public static final String COLUMN_HEIGHT = "Height";
public static final String COLUMN_REACH = "Reach";


SQLiteDatabase db;



public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ID1 TEXT,Name TEXT,Age INTEGER,Weight INTEGER,Height TEXT,Reach TEXT)");


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    this.onCreate(db);
}



//Add new row to the database
public boolean insertData(String id1, String name, String age, String weight, String height, String reach) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ID, id1);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT, weight);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, height);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_REACH, reach);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_PRODUCTS, null);
    return res;
}

public boolean updateData(String id1,String name, String age, String weight, String height, String reach) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ID, id1);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_AGE, age);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_WEIGHT, weight);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_HEIGHT, height);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_REACH, reach);
    db.update(TABLE_PRODUCTS, contentValues, "ID1 = ?", new String[] {id1 });
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData (String id) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   return db.delete(TABLE_PRODUCTS, "ID1 = ?", new String[] {id});
}
```

Comment: If you are using a database then use SQL to check for occurences of that ID you got from your user. If it is there then warn your user. Your code not helping at all. Where is your database?

Comment: There is my database, sorry i taught you would check for that in the other class my fault.

Comment: change ID1 TEXT  to ID1 TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE

Comment: Just tried it, seems to be allowing double entries still.. any other ideas?

Comment: Changing only the CREATE TABLE statement itself [is not enough](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run).

Comment: What should i change in the MainActivity?

Comment: He says uninstall your app and start over. Because your onCreate meyhod in sql helper class will not be executed twice.

Comment: Thank you so much!